# How should source code files be organized? By function, or type?

Tags: language-agnostic

In my early coding days, I would tend to group classes that functioned in a similar way. For example:

- Data transfer objects

  - Object A
  - Object B
- Dialogs

  - Dialog A
  - Dialog B

After a while, it started to frustrate me that when I was working on a particular part of the application, I would have to jump all around to piece it together.

In the last few years, I tend to organize things by feature. Classes that are commonly shared, such as database objects, I still keep together. I think this even makes sense for things like websites:

- Page A

  - images
  - Resource 1
  - Dialog 1
- Page B

  - images
  - Resource 2
  - Dialog 2

Is this the best way to do it? Does anyone have a good rule of thumb to follow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Java, packages are the unit of reuse.

For Python, modules (as well as packages) are the unit(s) of reuse.

The package should be a stand-alone thing.

If you put all data transfer objects into one big package, you don't have something terribly reusable.  You might not *want* all those data transfer object definitions.

If you put things together by "entity" -- the model, the views, the controls, the data access, etc. -- then you have a reusable module that can be shared in other applications.

Answer (score 4):

The 'Package-by-Feature' approach seems sensible and works for me, certainly for Java... how often do you want to pack up your data access layer, vs. that nifty new feature?

I thought the analysis ["Package by feature, not layer"](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=205) at javapractises.com was pretty easy to read, and covered a couple of angles I'd not thought about, like how package by feature works in other domains than programming, too.

Comment: Thank you! I found that link very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You should do it the way other code using your language/tools do it.  This is not a language-agnostic question; some languages/tools expect a relationship between 'file organization' and 'what's in those files' and you should respect that.